# How to resolve this sinopia installation error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sinopia

I am using redhat5.9. I found the 'make' related exception. I am wondering what are they making? I think they are just javascript relatd stuff.

```
[root@xxxx bin]# npm install -g sinopia --python=/usr/local/clo/ven/python-2.7.11/bin/python

> crypt3@0.1.8 install /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/4.2.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/crypt3/crypt3.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/crypt3/crypt3.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-406.el5
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> fs-ext@0.4.5 install /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/fs-ext
> node-gyp configure build

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/4.2.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/fs-ext/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/fs-ext/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fs-ext/fs-ext.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fs-ext/fs-ext.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/fs-ext/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-406.el5
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/fs-ext
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing crypt3@0.1.8
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fs-ext@0.4.5
-
> dtrace-provider@0.4.0 install /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install gyp globally using sudo, then install module

```
sudo npm install -g gyp 
sudo npm install /your module/
```

Comment: thanks what does 'sudo npm install /your module/' mean? I switched to directory  ../lib/node_modules/node-gyp and execute 'npm install', but still getting this error

Comment: did you try sudo npm install ?

Comment: What operation system are you using ?